# How do I make a new title for page headers only?

Tags: titles

I have an incredibly long title for my article, which overflows the headers. As such, I thought about a having a shorter, resumed version to put there. Through my research, I got the following command:

```
\title{short version}[looooooooooong version]
```

But this didn't work. This replace the true title and did something weird before it, as if trying to squeeze the long title into a 10px-wide box.

After that, I stopped understanding anything I found through my research – it got a little too complicated for me...

How can I have my article the way it is, but with a better title *only* for the headers?

Comment: Try with `\title[short]{long}`

Comment: Yes, that worked! If you want to post this as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a confusion in the order of brackets. Although there are some exceptions, the most usual syntax for a command (aka control sequence) with an optional argument is:

```
\command[<optional argument>]{<mandatory argument>} % in this order
```

Examples of use:

```
\command{whatever} % the mandatory argument is "whatever"
\command[whatsoever]{whatever} % the optional argument is "whatsoever"
\command{} % the mandatory is "nothing" (but there are an argument
\command whatever % the mandatory argument is "w" (first character after the command) 
                  % ("atever" is plain text and cannot be in the preamble)
```

As  `\title` closely follow this syntax, an example of use  could be some like:

```
\title[Red Cap Drama]{Little Red Riding Hood causes the murder of a poor wolf}
```